# Azure Devops: Approval for several Service Endpoints as a whole

Tags: deployment, azure-devops, yaml

I´m configuring a YAML deployment pipeline for a certain app which includes several service endpoints (of different types). Deployment of this app must have an approbal from the owner of all these resources. Problem comes from the fact that you can configure an approval for each service endpoint, but not for the whole set. Due to this, the resource owner receives 5 approval requests every time the app is being deployed (and every of these has to be approbed individually).

Any way of grouping the approval of several service endpoints in only one approval step? (Looking for something like Environments, where an "Environment level" approval can be set giving acces to the whole set of resources of that Environment. Sadly, I can not put a service endpoint there, only VM´s o Kubernetes).

Remark: I think this can be achieved with classic pipelines setting a stage approval, but my requirement is using YAML.

Regards.

Comment: Hi AFAIK the resource owner can click `approval All` to approve at once. Please check out below answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid that there is no such a feature in azure devops to group the approval requests of service endppoints currently.

Actually, the resource owner doesnot need to click multiple times to approve each individual approval request for a pipeline run.  He can simply click `Approval All` to approve at once

In my test yaml pipeline, I included several service endpoints in my yaml pipeline. When i run the pipeline. The resource owner will receive the approval requests. He can click the `Approval All` button to approve all the requests in a single click, he can also choose to approve each specific approval request. See below screenshot.

[image]

If above `approval all` feature in azure devops can not achieve what you expect with grouping the approval requests of service endpoints. You can [suggest a feature](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) to microsoft development team. Hope they will consider implementing this feature in the future sprint.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Levi Lu. If I´m not wrong even when you can approve all together, one mail will be sent for every request. Any way of avoiding this? Regards.

Comment: I am afraid there is no way to configure that. You can [submit a user voice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) to microsoft develop regarding this issue.